Parse Error on VS Code tasks.json when trying to execute a Python command
I have a custom pip package installed in the standard 'site-packages' path.
I would like to execute one of the Python files within that folder via a Task in VS Code tasks.json.
Since I do not want to hard code the 'site-packages' path, I need to fetch the corresponding 'site-packages' path of whoever is executing it.
Therefore, I wrote the following Task in VS Code. Unfortunately, I keep getting Parse Error on both Windows and Linux/macOS. The related solutions I found on the internet so far, did not help. I was wondering if any of you here faced this particular issue and found a solution. Thank you.
Executing the same Powershell commands within Powershell works perfectly fine however it does not work within the tasks.json.
My code:
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "label": "Run Python File",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "sh",
        "args": [
            "-c",
            "python3 -c 'import site'; 'print(site.getusersitepackages())' | xargs -I {} python3 {}/folder1/folder2/mypythonfile.py"
        ],
        "windows":{
          "command": "powershell",
          "args": [
            "-Command",
            "& { $sitePackages = python -c 'import site; print(site.getusersitepackages())'; $scriptPath = Join-Path $sitePackages '\\folder1\\folder2\\mypythonfile.py'; python $scriptPath }",
          ]
        },
        "group": "test",
        "presentation": {
          "reveal": "always",
          "panel": "new"
        }
      }
    ]
  }

Output on Windows:
Executing task: powershell -Command '& { $sitePackages = python -c 'import site; print(site-getusersitepackages())'; $scriptPath = Join-Path $sitePackages 'taf_scripts\taf_sac\taf_yaml_converter.py'; python $scriptPath }'

ParserError:
Line |
   1 |
     | ... ges = python -c 'import site; print (site.getusersitepackages ())'; $sc ...
     | An expression was expected after '('.

The terminal process "C: \Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe -Command powershell -Command '& { $sitePackages = python -c 'import site; print (site-getusersitepackages ())'; ScriptPath - Join-Path $sitePackages 'taf_scripts\taf_sac\taf_yaml_converter.py'; python $scriptPath }'" terminated with exit code: 1.
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

Output on Linux:
 *  Executing task: sh -c 'python3 -c 'import site'; 'print(site.getusersitepackages())' | xargs -I {} python3 {}/folder1/folder2/mypythonfile.py' 

zsh: parse error near `)'

 *  The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-l', '-c', 'sh -c 'python3 -c 'import site'; 'print(site.getusersitepackages())' | xargs -I {} python3 {}/folder1/folder2/mypythonfile.py''" failed to launch (exit code: 1). 
 *  Press any key to close the terminal. 

